# Error using dynamic keyword in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am getting this long error when i accpet the parameter as dynamic on my server side action method in mvc 4.

> {"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not
>   contain a definition for
>   'TournamentId'","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException","StackTrace":"
>   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )\r\n   at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0)\r\n   at
>   ManagerDeTorneos.Web.Controllers.TournamentDateController.Create(Object
>   data) in
>   F:\Prince\Projects\Juan\trunk\ManagerDeTorneos.Web\Controllers\TournamentDateController.cs:line
>   133\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c_*DisplayClass13.b*_c(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddMatch(dynamic data)
{
    int tournamentDateId = (int)data.TournamentDateId.Value;
    var tournamentDate = Catalog.TournamentDateRepository.GetById(tournamentDateId);
    if (tournamentDate == null)
    {
        throw ExceptionHelper.NotFound("Fecha no encontrada!");
    }
```

In The above method data Contains tournamentId as sent from ajax call as `JSON.Stringify({'TournamentId':'5'}).`

Can anybody tell me what is the cause of error. I even replaced the dll of Newtonsoft.Json as well

Comment: I am not sure, but instead of `dynamic`, passing `object` as action method parameter is a good idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right dan but i fixed my issue by removing that dll from GAC.  May be in GAC it was using old assembly

Comment: This saved me alot of time. Had no clue why this error was happening but now it works fine! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that you typed your parameter as `dynamic`, which means that the model binder doesn't know what to make it.  It's the same as if you were to declare it as an `object`.  Since you are providing JSON, it serializes the object as a Json.Net `JObject`.  Just because you define it as a `dynamic` doesn't mean that it's going to magically take whatever shape you need it to.

Change it to a concrete type - something that matches the structure of the provided JSON:

```
public class TournamentInfo
{
    public int TournamentId { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddMatch(TournamentInfo data)
{
    int tournamentDateId = data.TournamentId;
    var tournamentDate = Catalog.TournamentDateRepository.GetById(tournamentDateId);
    if (tournamentDate == null)
    {
        throw ExceptionHelper.NotFound("Fecha no encontrada!");
    }
```

This way, the binder knows what it's supposed to turn the JSON into, and since `TournamentInfo` matches the structure of the JSON, it won't have any trouble serializing it.

Don't misuse `dynamic`.  It was not introduced into C# so developers could stop defining classes.